# Check if URL is a valid SPWeb in an SPSite

Tags: 2013, spweb

I have a URL and I want to check if it exists as sub-site for a given URL.

- I have a URL = `www.go.com`
- I want to check if = www.go.com has URL = `www.go.com/abx` or not

I have +1000 sub webs, do I have to loop them all, no shortcut?

Comment: Are you using Server side code or client side code?

Comment: server side code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with what Supermode and Unnie have suggested, you may also choose to use the below code as well:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://www.go.com/"))    
{    
        using (SPWeb oWeb= site.OpenWeb())
        {
            SPWeb IsWebExists = oWeb.Webs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "abx");
            if (IsWebExists == null)
            {
                  //Your Code
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://www.go.com/"))
{
  using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb("abx"))
  {
     if (web.Exists)
         Console.WriteLine("exists");
     else
         Console.WriteLine("not exists");

  }
}
```

Just make sure inside `site.OpenWeb`, you provide the site relative url of the web

Comment: it no working//

Comment: @CustomizedName what is the url you gave in site.OpenWeb()?

Comment: exactly this no work; please test and confirm if it does

Comment: i have tested in a console app in my machine. Just make sure the urls are correct

Comment: You might want to try the OpenWeb(string, bool) overload and setting the bool parameter to true. By default if the specified URL doesn't exist, SharePoint will open the parent site. If you set the second parameter to true, it will explicitly check for the existence of a web at the specified URL and web.Exists will return false if the site doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
string serverUrl = "http://myserver";
string siteUrl = "/sites/SiteCollection";
string subSiteUrl = "This Subsite Does Not Exist";
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(serverUrl + siteUrl))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(subSiteUrl))
    {
        if (web.Exists)
        {
            // do work with the web...
            Console.WriteLine(site.Url);
            Console.WriteLine(web.Url);
        }
    }
}
```